# Squid to cache youtube and windows update content

Tags: ubuntu, squid, update, transparent-proxy

I Have a squid server (transparent) and I want to cahce youtube videos and windows updates. I know that someone has posted a similar question and I have looked at this post but I am configuring this with webmin and would like to know how to set it up so that I can add other dynamic content on other sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube has recently [added support for caching their videos](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/06/browsers-cache-youtube-videos.html). This is specific for YouTube (ie. Viddler probably doesn't work for example), but it should also work with Squid with no extra modification.

Comment: Not particularly noticed it working here - but will have a fiddle, see if we can make it play ball...

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily the ideal solution but I run ipCop and use the [Advanced Proxy](http://www.advproxy.net/) add-on to cache updates from an array of sources along with WSUS. It works brilliantly.

The disadvantage is the add-on only works with ipCop and Smoothwall, but I feel it is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to cache Windows Updates in that manner. For cacheing them, check Microsoft's [WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/wsus/default.aspx).

Comment: windows updates is not so much an issue as we have a wsus server in production.

Comment: Is this question still correct?

Answer (score 0):

I always thought [This](http://cachevideos.com/) looked interesting for caching vids. Disclaimer: yet to try it.

Comment: I tried it it doesnt seem to cache though.  I installed it on an ubuntu server by converting the rpm to deb with alien.

Comment: You sure it is interacting correctly with squid?

Comment: I believe so...it might be how I have it configured.

Answer (score 0):

**Caching Windows Updates is definitely possible! (with tweaking)**

I recently setup a Squid server on Ubuntu 10.04 with Webmin and was able to make it cache Windows updates. I used the Webmin docs to tweak the default settings.

I changed the max file size from 20MB to 5GB, and increased the total cache size from 100MB to 40GB.

Links to reference...

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/WindowsUpdate

http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/SquidProxyServer

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/squid.html